# How to generate multiple report in Report Viewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I actually pass employee id of a single employee and that it generate report for employee but how can i do this if there are multiple employee having same criteria . if store procedure generation multiple employee data than That much reports should be generated.As i am new to this, help me out.... Thanks :)

Comment: Hi I have the same requirement - I want to know how to reuse a SSRS report to show multiple times in Report Viewer by passing multiple id's (ideally without changing the report to accept multiple id's).

Answer (score 1):

Can you put some code so that i will update it

anyway!

There are some portions in a report. Report header, report footer, page header, page footer and then content header and detail now you have to design your report in such a way that you have to group employee id. Grouping is very important in reports.

You can easily find what i have mentioned.

You have to mention what reporting tool you are using then i will give you more detail

Here are some useful links

- http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/creating-a-report-with-crystal-reports-10.html
- http://www.softwaremedia.com/software-guides/crystal-reports-setup.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to print each employee that match your criteria, assuming you're using a rdlc file in visual studio you just have to use a List from the toolbox menu, it will group your employees by your criteria.